# Ability to Send Bitcoins to an Address over a duration of time

Tags: sending, recurring-payments, smartcontracts

Is there a service or upcoming feature which lets you send Bitcoins to an address over a duration of time? I can write a script myself to send 1mbtc every day to an address and leave it running on my computer/server. But I was wondering if there was a service that does this already? Or can smart contracts do this, if so which one?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for an automated billing solution, or something along those lines. There may be others, but I know Coinbase has support for this. This is a screen shot from their online interface:

---

[image]

---

If it was a recurring payment in small amounts, you might also consider [Micropayment Channels](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#micropayment-channel), so that the feels were not prohibitive. For larger, monthly or yearly transactions, though, the fees paid to the miners may not be as noticeable.